# Dart : Why should overriding method's parameter be "wider" than parent's one? (probably topic about Contravariant)

Tags: dart

https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#extending-a-class

```
class Television {
  // ···
  set contrast(int value) {...}
}

class SmartTelevision extends Television {
  @override
  set contrast(num value) {...}
  // ···
}
```

> Argument types must be the same type as (or a supertype of) the
> overridden method’s argument types. In the preceding example, the
> contrast setter of SmartTelevision changes the argument type from int
> to a supertype, num.

As explained above, why should the "overriding method argument type" be "wider" than the "parent class method argument type"?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Function_types

I've seen the above pages, but I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you are given a `Television`; you don't know what *type* of `Television`. You want to set its contrast, so you look up the signature of the `contrast` method on the `Television` class, and pass a value that is valid according to that signature.

If what you've actually been given is a `SmartTelevision`, and it defines a *more limited* set of values that are accepted, something's going to go wrong; but as long as it accepts *at least the same values* as the base definition on `Television`, everything will be fine.

Now, if you *know* you have a `SmartTelevision`, you can look up that class, and see that it accepts *additional* values, *as well as* the ones that all `Television`s accept. You can pass in one of those - even if it turns out what you really have is an even more specialised `SonySmartTelevision` which extends `SmartTelevision`.

---

For completeness, let's talk about *return values* which *go the other way*. Let's say we have a `getContrast` method; one thing we might do is get that value from one `Television`, and set another `Television` to match. That should be fine, if the return type of `getContrast` matches the parameter type of `contrast`.

So what happens if we read the contrast from a `SmartTelevision` and it gives us a value that our other `Television` doesn't accept? That's not going to work. Luckily, if the `Television` class defines a return type in its signature, that acts as a contract that sub-classes have to follow; they're *not allowed* to return values outside that range.

On the other hand, we can have a `CheapTelevision` where the `getContrast` method can only return a very limited set of values. As long as those values are in the range promised by `Television`, this is fine.

---

So, we say that *inputs are contravariant*, allowing the same or wider values in sub-classes; but *outputs are covariant*, allowing the same or narrower values in sub-classes.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.
I am very busy right now, so I will find time to read it.